# Function not defined message in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am building a game in JavaScript along with html5. I want my front page to display a bit of text and then when I press any button suppose if <kbd>p</kbd> then the actual game starts.

I have used flag in this case to toggle between two functions one which brings the front page and another which is actually starting the game.
Here's my code:

```
var flag1 =true;
function init() 
 {
  canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  region = canvas.getContext('2d');
  if(flag1==true)
   {
    front();
   }
  else
   {
    start();
   }  
 }
function front()
 {
   document.write("press p to play");

   document.onkeydown = function(event) 
   {

     var keyCode; 
     if(event == null)
    {
     keyCode = window.event.keyCode; 
    }
    else 
    {
    keyCode = event.keyCode; 
    }

    switch(keyCode)
    {
       case 80:
       flag1=false;
       init();
       break;
    
       default: 
       break;

     }
 }
 }

 function start()
 {
  *************
   *********
  *********
 }
```

This code is giving an error in console whenever I press <kbd>p</kbd>, i.e.

> init() is not defined

Can anyone sort this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer: http://jsfiddle.net/morrison/HrRD6/**

**Notes:**

- There's no point in finding canvas again if you've already found it. **Storing the canvas to lib.canvas and not retrieving it again seems to be what fixed the problem.**
- **Use library-style functions**.  This helps avoid naming conflicts.
- **Tidy your code.**  I use [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) a lot, so I run it through there, or you can try [formatjavascript](http://www.formatjavascript.com/) or [javascriptbeautifier](http://www.javascriptbeautifier.com/).

Comment: I cleaned up my answer. Bullet one has the answer to your problem.  The others are just useful tips.

Answer (score 0):

init() runs for me in chrome. Which browser are you using? What scope is the code in?

Also, as far as I know, JavaScript might be misparsed if it is not indented like so:

```
if (bool) {
  // stuff
}
```

Try running your code through [jslint](http://jslint.com).

Comment: It runs once, press p and it fails.  Verified this myself.

Comment: init() is perfectly defined in chrome. Which browser are you using?The function is of pretty low quality however, checking a global variable and running its calling function.

Comment: You haven't ran his code.  Here's an online version: http://jsfiddle.net/WgQ5w/ Run it and look in your console.  When you press p with your focus in the content box, it throws an error.

Comment: Yes, it throws an error, but it's completely unrelated to init() being defined. Chrome's console throws the same error.

Comment: He makes an assumption: `This code is giving an error in console when ever i press p , ie. init() is not defined.`  He doesn't care about init() being defined: he cares about the error.

Comment: i have defined init @Levi Morrison , and what i think is scope of switch is inside a function and init() is defined outside that function.

Comment: @Anuj, you do realize that scoping this into libraries helps you fix this problem, right?  See my answer.  It fixes your problem.

Comment: @Levi Yeah it did Finally ! Thanks

Comment: @Anuj: be sure to accept my post as the answer.  It's just how this site works :)